# If $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$ then there is some $L$-structure $\mathcal{R}$ and elementary embeddings between them.

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Let $L$ be a language and $\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}$ be $L$-structures. Suppose $\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{N}$ are elementarily equivalent. Prove that there is some $L$-structure $\mathcal{R}$ and elementary embeddings $f:\mathcal{M} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ and $g:\mathcal{N} \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$.

My first attempt was to take $\mathcal{R}=\mathcal{N}$. Then the identity map is an elementary embedding from $\mathcal{N}$ to $\mathcal{R}$. It remains to show there is an elementary embedding from $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{N}$. However, being elementarily equivalent does not imply the existence of elementary embedding. So my method wouldn't work.

Then I have to construct this $L$-structure $\mathcal{R}$ so to make it satisfy the desired property. How can I construct it?

Comment: Hint. Expand the language by giving each element of $\mathcal M$ and each element of $\mathcal N$ a name. Let $T_1$ and $T_2$ be the theories of $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ in the expanded language, and let $T=T_1\cup T_2$. Use elementary equivalence of $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ to show that each finite subset of $T$ is satisfiable; conclude by compactness that $T$ is satisfiable; let $\mathbb R$ be a model of $T$; observe that $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ are elementarily embeddable in $\mathcal R$.

Comment: @bof, I have a maybe unrelated question: does $Th(\mathcal{M}) = Th(\mathcal{N})$ imply $|M|=|N|$?

Comment: @bbw No, Lowenheim-Skolem says in many cases, there will be models of $Th(\mathcal M)$ of any infinite cardinality and all models of a complete theory have the same theory (namely that complete theory).

Comment: If $|M|$ means the cardinality of the underlying set of $\mathcal M$, [not necessarily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem).

Comment: @bof, by "expand the language", do you mean taking $L_1=L \cup M$ and $L_2=L \cup N$ or you mean taking $L'=L \cup M \cup N$?

Comment: The latter.$\ $

Comment: @bof, thank you.